# Radio Buttons as Images, checked and unchecked state (jquery)

Tags: jquery, css

I'm pretty new to jquery and I've been searching for hours trying to create radio buttons as images - a user can click on to fill out a questionnaire. I don't want to use jqueryui because the images are too difficult to recreate with jquery and css.

10 questions - 3 answers per question.

I've finally found this one that seems the most useful
http://screwdefaultbuttons.com/

I would like to display 3 separate images for each radio button plus 3 images when any of them are checked.

Can someone help? Right now it's only one graphic for checked and one for unchecked.

If someone has a different solution - that would be helpful too!

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can have separate class for each of your differently styled image and in css add images for that class.

Comment: Do you think I can do it outside of the plugin scope?

Comment: @flaming_nonsense I think so, look at how screwdefaultbuttons.com suggest to style using css.

Comment: Each button is a separate image though - and I want it to be another image when it's checked will that intefere? Right now it's `$('input:radio').screwDefaultButtons({
  checked:  "url(images/question1_checked.png)",
  unchecked: "url(images/question1_unchecked.png)",
  width:  447,
  height:  58
 });`   But I want to address each radio button separately within one group

Answer (score 0):

Wow this took awhile and with the help of a good friend here is what I came up with.

I have multiple groups of radio buttons with the same name for each group and a different id per radio in group.

```
          <input type="radio" class="question" name="question1" id="q1A" value="A" /><label class="answer" for="q1A">Answer1</label>
          <input type="radio" class="question" name="question1" id="q1B" value="B" /><label class="answer" for="q1B">Answer2</label>
          <input type="radio" class="question" name="question1" id="q1C" value="C" /><label class="answer" for="q1C">Answer3</label>
```

Then in my css I created a hidden class

```
.input_hidden {
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
```

}

set the class of the labels with the appropriate image, with hover etc.

For the jquery hide all the radio buttons - do it when the doc loads.

```
$('.question:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
```

so now only the labels will show and not the radio buttons. When you click on the graphic the radio buttons will be selected.

Comment: you can also use images instead of text (marked up with css) but if you have different images per radio button - that might be a bit much. Especially for checked and unchecked states